# Not able to find input type radio buttons , which i have to created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone

I am implementing Windows phone apps with PhoneGap and I am getting nothing As am not able to find input type radio buttons, which I have to created dynamically but it finding static input type radio buttons.

```
<div id="tablSettingDefaultHomeScreen" >
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div> 


function makeElements()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var tblResponding = " <li>"
         + "<label>" + i + "</label>";
        tblResponding = tblResponding + "<input name='group'  type='radio'  value='Cats' />";

        tblResponding = tblResponding  + "</li> ";
        $(toStaticHTML(tblResponding)).appendTo("#tablSettingDefaultHomeScreen ul");
    }
}

function getElements() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("group");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery then you can try [ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :-

for example :-

```
    $('input[type=radio]').on("click", function(event){
      alert('hi');
    });
```

[SEE THE WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mWkU4/1/)

Comment: Hi Pranav, thanks for help , i am using jquery and this is not working    have you try this code in ie.

Comment: see the final rendered HTML in firebug ...check whether your radio buttons are created or not ...if not then you need to check your makeElement function first

Comment: Here is the rendered HTML , have a look on this                                                                                <ul>
      <li><input id="ab" type="radio" value="Cats"></li>
<li><input id="ab" type="radio" value="Cats"></li>
<li><input id="ab" type="radio" value="Cats"></li>
<li><input id="ab" type="radio" value="Cats"></li>
<li><input id="ab" type="radio" value="Cats"></li></ul>

Comment: Since there is no input element with name "group" ..jquery selector  (even through normal javascript )cannot find it ..try the updated answer ..